# Disable onbeforeunload in Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I have an iframe in the page , but which has window.onbeforeunload , how to disable it?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ return "Reload?" }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

window.onbeforeunload = null;

This will work for disabling that event

Comment: Where should I write it? before or after the iframe?

Comment: to take it effect on iframe, try something like this   document.getElementById('iframe id').onclick = function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
};

Comment: @NagaSaiA's suggestion above doesn't work. The handler is on the document _inside_ the iframe, not on the iframe itself. At the level accessible to that event handler, `window` still points to the containing frame, not the iframe.